# Getting Current User - On Page Load (JavaScript)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server

Basically, what I want to achieve is to hide particular elements in all SharePoint sites within a single farm.

What I did is I created a *`SiteCode.js`* file inside the Site Assets folder and filled it with the following code:

```
function CallClientOM() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.website = context.get_web();
    this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert(currentUser.get_loginName());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    var siteActionsMenu = document.querySelectorAll("#siteactionid")[0];
    siteActionsMenu.parentNode.removeChild(siteActionsMenu);

    var topNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".brc-nav-toplinks-right")[0];
    topNavLinks.parentNode.removeChild(topNavLinks);
}

//window.onload = CallClientOM();

/*
$(document).ready(function() {
    CallClientOM();
});
*/
```

When I load this function inside Google Chrome Developer Tool `(CallClientOM())` I am actually able to hide those elements and see changes right away. But the problem is I cannot achieve this once the site loads.

I have tried two methods which are at the bottom (as comments).

I've also tried to wrap all code within `$(document).ready(function() {}` function, but with no success. It seems that I'm missing something or doing incorrectly.

How do I load this function once the site loads (without using Developer Tools or anything) before site content?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("CallClientOM");
```

because jQuerys ready function isn't reliable in SharePoint

http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/

or wait for sp.js:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadContext, 'sp.js');
    function loadContext() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
    }
```

#### There is way more to understand

read all 6 blogs by Hugh Wood: http://www.spcaf.com/blog/sharepoint-javascript-context-dev-part-1/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I suppose it did worked but it appears that once the site page loads it throws an error in the 2nd line: var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); which says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined". It's strange because when I try to run this CallClientOM in the console I don't get any errors...

Comment: Because once you start typing in the console SP.js has loaded.. and jQuerys ready does not fire at the correct time. You have to wait for SP.js

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getWebUserData = function (){
    this.context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.web = this.context.get_web();
    this.currentUser = this.web.get_currentUser();
    this.currentUser.retrieve();
    this.context.load(this.web);

    this.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), 
                                   Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}
// this will return Currently log in User
this.onSuccessMethod = function (){
    alert(this.currentUser.get_title());
}

//will show alert Message is failed to retrieve Information
this.onFailureMethod = function (){
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){
var thisUserAccount=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Title",debug: false});

  $('#lblfrom').text(thisUserAccount);
});

Answer (score 0):

I added this script into my masterpage for getting the users department and after that I change a link in the navigation. Here the beginning of it and how to get the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetCurrentUser() {

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccessA,
  error : onErrorA
});
}

function onSuccessA(data, request){

    // alert("Success One");
    // cutting of i:0#.w|

    //console.log(data.d);
    //var emailAdresse = data.d.Email;
    //alert(emailAdresse);

    var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];

    var repOne = "%5C";  
    var repTwo = "%2E";
    // alert("before replace: " + loginName);

    loginName = loginName.replace(/\\/g, repOne); // replace \ with %5C
    loginName = loginName.replace(/\./g, repTwo); // replace . with %2E

    // alert("after replace: " + loginName);

    GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginName); // call next function to get department. Pass the loginname into the function
}

function onErrorA(error) {

  alert(error);
}

GetCurrentUser();

});
</script>
```

Hope this will help you a little.