# How to show a label on a load of javascript function ex logged in user in script editor in sharepoint webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, office365apis

I am facing a issue.I am adding a web-part in which I am showing current user logged  in script editor through embedded  code.I want to show current user when sharepoint open.I am getting on click but i want to add when load the page.How can i do it.

Code for clicking a button and get the current user in sharepoint in alert message box

```
<input type='button' id='id1' value='Get User Name' onclick="GetLoggedInUserName();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetLoggedInUserName()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = context.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
context.load(currentUser);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
{
 alert(currentUser.get_loginName());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

How can we do it on load.

Thanx in Advance guys

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetLoggedInUserName");
```

because jQuerys ready function isn't reliable in SharePoint

Check the more information [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163656/getting-current-user-on-page-load-javascript)

Comment: Did you get it working?